# EntryPointNotFoundException thrown when reading from Header collection in HttpRequest

Tags: c#, .net, azure, httprequest

I have an Azure Function with a HTTP Trigger to handle a webhook.  It's all working fine (function being triggered, reading the POST body) until I try to check for a value in the http request Headers collection.

The request is a `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpRequest`, which appears to be an Abstract base class, being instantiated behind the scenes to`DefaultHttpRequest`.

The offending lines of code are

```
var requestBody = await (new StreamReader(req.Body)).ReadToEndAsync();  // works fine
if (req.Headers.ContainsKey("X-Payload-Digest"))  // crashes out, can't read from Headers
{
    req.Headers.TryGetValue("X-Payload-Digest", out var secretKey);
}
```

The code throws an exception when trying to retrieve or check anything from the `Headers` collection property of the `HttpRequest req` variable.

The funny thing is, whilst debugging I can pause execution and run `req.Headers.ContainsKey("X-Payload-Digest")` just fine in the VS 2022 immediate window.  Yet it fails when stepping through the code.  Even in debug, pausing on breakpoints.

The debugger links out to `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors TaskMethodInvoker -> FunctionInvoker`, which returns `Result = "{Not yet computed}"`

And the eventual Exception thrown is `EntryPointNotFoundException`

One theory was that it's down to async / await, with it trying to read from `req.Headers` too soon before it's hydrated, but I don't think that's it.  Another hypothesis is that maybe it's referencing an incorrect Assembly or dll, where the Headers collection itself isn't available as a property or it's available methods are different, which seems more likely but I can't figure out how or why.  Or if it's even the case!

All thoughts welcome on this, I'm stumpted!

Comment: Additional information will be helpful. Like what version of .NET and if the function is running in-process or isolated. They're different implementations. Based on what I see I'd guess in-process.